# Using an NSViewController Component in another XIB with XCode GUI Builder?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

This is a beginners question about Cocoa and Objective-C.

I have created an encapsulated reuseable GUI component with an Cocoa NSViewController class and a XIB resource file. Now i would like to use this component in other XIB files but can't figure out how to do that.

I want something like the custom views that you can just use as a placeholder to position and size after assigning the class name.

While i can create the controller class as an object in the xib i don't know how to connect the view. Currently i'm just using an additional custom view where i add my component at loading time with some code. But i'm sure there must be a better way without explicit coding.

Comment: Suppose your custom class is a subclass of ```NSView``` named ```MyGUI``` then add an NSView and in storyboard, in the **Custom Class** section's **Class** field enter the class of your component ie ```MyGUI```. Then when you drag from storyboard, Xcode will add it as a ```MyGUI``` type and you can use it as such in your code.

Comment: I'm using xib not storyboards.

Comment: Works the same ...

Comment: what I meant with drag from storyboard really is drag from XIB editor. I have done this in iOS with XIB files and ```UIView```s for custom, reusable GUI classes. Sometimes those classes are then wrapped into view controllers as the main view of the controller and sometimes not - both work well and I am pretty sure you can do the same here. The worst will be that you need to lift the ```NSView``` from the controller to stand on its own. I've had to do that and even went as far as hand-editing the XIB file sometimes as it can be tricky to do in Xcode.

Comment: @Lothar **Nib** is a historical (binary) file format which is **Xib** (xml) today and **storyboards** keep Xib's in relation to each other so it can hold interactive relations between "xib parts".